# Run latest version of G-WAN on windows

Tags: windows, g-wan

I see some comments in G-WAN website about discontinuing Windows version since Sep 9, 2009.

Now, I want to run the latest version of G-WAN web server in Windows, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you'll have to convince Microsoft to update their issues which are slowing down G-WAN.

:)  It's currently not very profitable to invest time in Windows when the bottlenecks are coming from the OS (from my understanding).

But, if you *really* want to run the latest version in Windows, you'll probably have to go down the virtualization route, and even then you'll still be depending on Linux to power it.